# jQuery not receiving JSON encoded data from PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get jQuery to retrieve PHP variables and insert them into input values. I was looking everywhere trying to find a solution.

Here's jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready() {
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'loadstuff.php',
      data: {
            'something': something, 
            'different': different, 
            'another': another
            },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        $('input[name=get_seomething_here]').val( 'something' );
        $('input[name=get_different_here]').val( 'different' );
        $('input[name=get_another_here]').val( 'another' );
}
    });

});
});
```

And here's PHP side.

```
//connecting to db etc.

$query = "SELECT something, different, another FROM stuff WHERE id='1'";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo(json_encode(array('something' => $row['something'], 
'different' => $row['different'], 
'another' => $row['another']
)));
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the header to text/json? Before your echo in the PHP, put: header('Content-type: text/json');

Comment: @kingcoyote The proper `Content-type` for json is `application/json`; so it should look like `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is force `JSON_NUMBERIC_CHECK`, or all PHP numbers will be converted to JavaScript string types. If the cols you're querying contain no numbers, you won't have to worry, but you should do it since it's a good habit.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact I wanted the script to pass some numbers as well. Right now, as I modified the script using aletzo advise, it turned out in strange way. The purpose of this script (as presented one is just an example) was to fill 9 input text fields with numbers and at the same time fill drop down select input values for a sort-of calculator - however in the end it gave all selected inputs the same value (adding the values together and giving each the same) and still didnt fill the input text

Comment: Could you possibly create a jsfiddle with the actual code, and tell us the exact error that you get? Probably it's gonna very easy to solve the problem that way.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

```
$('input[name=get_seomething_here]').val( data.something );
$('input[name=get_different_here]').val( data.different );
$('input[name=get_another_here]').val( data.another );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed the code following your suggestion. However, the data still cant get through for some reason...

Answer (score -1):

aletzo is right.. but before doing that you have to do like:

```
data = eval("(" + data + ")");
```

Then you can use data.something, data.different and data.another

Comment: I've been doing this myself, and `eval()` is not only unnecessary, but can leave a web app vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: you can use JSON.parse rather then eval

Comment: Nonetheless, calling an extra method when it's unnecessary is inefficient.